# Overwrite CSS from application.css / selectize.js

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using `selectize-rails` gem and it doesn't look good because of the CSS from `application.css` being applied to it...

**application.css:**

```
.label {
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

I created separated css file for that particular view and copied as above into it and replaced the color with `color: black !important;`, similar with other params... But it doesn't give any effect. The label color is still white. Please help!

Comment: You need to Load your custom css file after you load application css file on your layout or view file

Comment: @sa77 it's loaded, I mean it applies the style for other elements but not `.label`

Comment: I assume you are removing .label and adding your class.

Comment: Have you used a dom  explorer on your loaded page to see exactly what css rules are being applied?